# Slidedowned element height

Tags: jquery, css, height, css-position, slidedown

I have a grid, i have absolute positioned boxes in it. The boxes have a head part and a page part which is hidden... when i click on a button, all boxes will be hidden and the selected one becomes 100% wide and its hidden page slides down to be shown.
My problem is that the part of my website which is under the grid (my footer) is hidden by the slided down pages because the grid's height does not push down the downer parts of the website...
I can not give fix height for the grid because different contents will be variable... I do notr understand why my relative positioned grid's height is not calculated by the system...

HTML structure :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <button class="showclick">Show</button>
        <button class="hideclick">Hide</button>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-head"></div>
            <div class="page"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">This is my footer which should be under the slide-downed (shown) page</div>
</div>
```

I guess the problem is with my CSS. But as the system is complex, i am not sure that i can change the positioning and overflows in it...

```
body {position:relative;display:block;max-width:800px;min-height:101vh; margin:0 auto;overflow-x:hidden}
.content {position:relative;display:block;width:100%;padding:5%;background:blue}

.header {position:relative;display:block;width:100%;background:orange}
.showclick, .hideclick {position:relative;width:20%;height:30px}

.grid {position:relative;display:block;min-height:500px;background:grey}
.grid:after {content:'';display:block;clear:both}
.box {position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:200px;color:#fff;background:#a2c5bf}
.box-head {position:relative;display:block;width:100%;height:200px;background:red;overflow:hidden}
.page {position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;padding:5%;background:yellow}

.footer {position:relative;display:block;width:100%;text-align:center;background:green}
```

Is it possible to calculate the grid (or page) height with jquery with the button click ?

Fiddle is here : https://jsfiddle.net/igorlaszlo/zcubarw7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your CSS code with below one

**CSS:**

```
body {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    max-width:800px;
    min-height:101vh;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
    text-size-adjust:100%;
    background:#fff
}
.content {position:relative;display:block;width:100%;padding:5%;background:blue}

.header {position:relative;display:block;width:100%;background:orange}
.showclick, .hideclick {position:relative;width:20%;height:30px}

.grid {position:relative;display:block;background:grey}
.grid:after {content:'';display:block;clear:both}
.box {position:relative;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;color:#fff;background:#a2c5bf}
.box-head {position:relative;display:block;width:100%;height:200px;background:red;overflow:hidden}
.page {position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;padding:5%;background:yellow}

.footer {position:relative;bottom:0;display:block;width:100%;text-align:center;background:green}
```

And check if it's as per your need or not. Tell me for further modification.

Comment: thanks but as i said i can not change css too much... i have not only one .box but many boxes with absolute position, because this is a grid. You proposed boxes position relative with top & left properties, it will not work... that is why i asked if there is a jquery solution... css trick would be ok too but sorry, yours does not work...

Comment: I changed the fiddle for better understandings... : https://jsfiddle.net/zcubarw7/6/

Comment: No need to worry....I've not set any parameter as fix value so you can use it in every condition.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did not find any answer, i tried with appending, i tried with cloning, i got an *actual(height)* plugin, but nothing helped... so i had to change the structure...

I took out the pages from the grid, like this i knew the exact height of it (boxes have heights in pixel). As boxes are absolute positioned, i put a fake div "under" them with the exact height of the grid.

The pages are shown-hidden under the grid / before the footer...

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <button class="showclick">Show</button>
        <button class="hideclick">Hide</button>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-head"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page"></div>
    <div class="footer">This is my footer which should be under the slide-downed (shown) page</div>
</div>
```

CSS (only changes)

```
.grid {position:relative;display:block;background:grey}/*no min-height*/
.grid:after {content:'';display:block;clear:both}
.fake {position:relative;display:block;width:100%;height:200px}/*new element*/
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/igorlaszlo/zcubarw7/7/